# Let $f:D(0,R)\rightarrow D(0,M)$ holomorphic function with $f(0)=0$ prove that $|f(z)|\leq \frac{M}{R}|z|$ for every $z \in D(0,R) $

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:**

> Let $f:D(0,R)\rightarrow D(0,M)$ holomorphic function with $f(0)=0$ prove that

> a.$|f(z)|\leq \frac{M}{R}|z|$ for every $z \in D(0,R) $

> b. $|f'(0)|\leq \frac{M}{R}$

**solution:**

$\cdot $ first case we assume $M\ge R$, th restriction of $f$ into $D(0,R)$ (meaning to restrict $f:D(0,R)\rightarrow D(0,R)$) gives us all the assumptions to the Schwarz lemma, and we have that

for every $z \in D(0,R) $ $|f(z)|\leq |z|$  since   $M\ge R\Rightarrow $  $|f(z)|\leq \frac{M}{R}|z|$ same we get  $|f'(0)|\leq \frac{M}{R}$

$\cdot $ second case $M<R$ since $D(0,R) \in D(0,R) $ does that mean for every $z \in D(0,R) $ $|f(z)|> |z|$ (!?) and since $M<R \Rightarrow$ $|f(z)|\leq \frac{M}{R}|z|$

i think my proof is waayy off can someone help me with a hint ?

Comment: Hint: WLOG we can assume $M=R=1$, then you might want to use maximum modulus theorem on $\frac{f(z)}{z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider $g(z)=f(Rz)/M,$ which satisfies the usual Schwarz Lemma hypotheses.

Comment: do you mean $Rf(z)/M$ ?

Comment: No. If $|z|<1,$ then $|Rz|<R, $ hence $|f(Rz)| <M,$ which gives $|f(Rz)/M| <1.$

Comment: but if i consider $g=Rf(z)/M$ i get $|g(z)| \leq |z|  $ and then i get $|f(z)|\leq \frac{M}{R}|z|$

Comment: What if $R=1/2$ and $z=3/4?$ What does $f(z)$ even mean?